# SharePoint 2010 Anonymous using SOAP 1.2 always leads to login prompt

Tags: authentication, anonymous-authentication, soap

SharePoint server has Anonymous Access configured, everything is working fine. But when I try to connect from SOAP 1.2 client it asks for credentials **(401 Forbidden), moreover it asks for NTLM authentication**. The major thing, that I have figured out so far, is that it only reacts to Content Type header in the request, if I change it to something different than **application/soap+xml** - it's working fine without any authentication requested. So it looks like that the problem is just the Content Type application/soap+xml (SOAP 1.2) which causes SharePoint to request NTLM authentication. If anyone had similar issue, please advise. I even don't know where to start from further investigation, no such an issue over the internet.

Working fine:

```
POST https://listetner.ashx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 527
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope>content</s:Envelope>
```

Not working:

```
POST https://listetner.ashx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 527
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope>content</s:Envelope>
```